# (Azure CDN Premium Verizon) Rules Engine: 301 Redirect all requests to azurewebsites.net and azureedge.net URLs

Tags: azure, redirect, azure-web-app-service, azure-cdn, verizon

Currently have an Azure CDN Premium Verizon (P1) Profile that is being used with an Azure Web App.

What is the best way to 301 redirect all requests to

YourWebsiteName.azureedge.net

and

YourWebsiteName.azurewebsites.net

To the Custom Domain: YourWebsiteName.com

Using the Rules Engine at https://cdn.windowsazure.com/http/rules/default.aspx

Don't want 3 URL's pointing to the same content.

Currently the URLs

1. YourWebsiteName.Com
2. YourWebsiteName.azureedge.net
3. YourWebsiteName.azurewebsites.net

**All points to the same exact content.**

SEO wise this is not good and would like to know what is the best way to redirect the Two Azure provided URLs to the Custom domain for all requests.

**When visiting all 3 URLs they work and I don't want them to.**

Only want the Custom Domain: YourWebsiteName.com to be accessible to the public and Search Engines.

Only want 1 Domain the Custom domain to point to the content of the website and not the Azure URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be needing the rules engine to point the other two URL's (*.azurewebsites.net and *.azureedge.net) to your custom domain.

To have the three URL's all point to the first one, i.e. the custom domain, you need to sign in into your service provider from whom you purchased the domain name, and then add two `CNAME` records, an `A` record and a `TXT` record as outlined in the two articles below.

1. **[Tutorial: Map an existing custom DNS name to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain)**

   a. Add a `CNAME` record to point your azure websites subdomain `yourwebsite.azurewebsites.net` to point to the `www` subdomain of your website `www.yourwebsite.com`.

   b. In the Azure portal, on your App Service panel, verify that `CNAME` you just added.

   c. In the DNS panel of your domain provider once again, create an `A` record that points to the IP address of your app service `yourwebsite.azurewebsites.net`.

   d. Finally, create a `TXT` record in the DNS panel of your domain provider to point the URL `yourwebsite.azurewebsites.net` to `yourwebsite.com` so that Azure may verify that you own the domain `yourwebsite.com`.
2. **[Tutorial: Add a custom domain to your Azure CDN endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain)**

   a. To verify your domain, add a `CNAME` that reads like `cdnverify.yourEndpointNameOnTheCDN.azureedge.net` and let it point to your CDN endpoint `yourEndpointNameOnTheCDN.azureedge.net`.

   b. To map your domain name to the CDN endpoint, create a second CNAME with the name of your custom domain `yourwebsitename.com` and let it point to your CDN endpoint `yourEndpointNameOnTheCDN.azureedge.net`.

Comment: This I already done, what I want to do is block access to the Azure URL's and do a 301 Redirect telling the search engines to use the Custom Domain URL only for indexing and not the Azure URL's